# Automatic form submission using JS

Tags: javascript

I am developing a code, which takes a value as input and the form when submitted, displays the result and the code is as follows:

```
<script>
function submitme()
{

    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>
<body onload="submitme()">
<FORM name="performance" id="myform" method="post" action="http://www.pvpsiddhartha.ac.in/index.sit" >
        <INPUT type="hidden" name="service" value="STU_PERFORMANCE_MARKS_DISPLAY">
          <TABLE border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <TR>
              <TD colspan="2" align="center"><STRONG><U>Student Marks Performance Display Form</U></STRONG></TD>
            </TR>  
            <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
            <TR>
              <TD align="right" width="40%">Regd. No:</TD>
              <TD><INPUT type="text" name="stid" value="<?php echo $_GET['x']; ?>"></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
            <TR>
              <TD align="right"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></TD>
              <TD align="center"><INPUT type="reset" value="Clear"></TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </FORM>
        </body>
```

The problem is, when the page is loaded completely, the form should be submitted , but the form cannot be submitted. What is the problem  , Help me!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script tag is not inside `<body>` nor `<head>`.

Comment: when I add an alert("hello"); , it is being invoked but the submition is not done @Bart

Comment: either use document.getElementById('myForm') or document.forms[0]

Comment: The same problem , i cant submit @OhadMilchgrub

Comment: there's a problem with the name of the button input that overrides the submit function of the form. change the name of the button from submit to something else (or remove it altogether)

Comment: you should run your code after form has been loaded. As @DmitrijPovasar said.

Answer (score 3):

Try this pure javascript,

```
  <body>
    <FORM name="performance" id="myform" method="post" action="http://www.pvpsiddhartha.ac.in/index.sit" >
      <INPUT type="hidden" name="service" value="STU_PERFORMANCE_MARKS_DISPLAY">
        <TABLE border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" align="center"><STRONG><U>Student Marks Performance Display Form</U></STRONG></TD>
          </TR>  
          <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="right" width="40%">Regd. No:</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="stid" value=""></TD>
          </TR>
          <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="right"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit"></TD>
            <TD align="center"><INPUT type="reset" value="Clear"></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </FORM>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById('myform').submit();
        };

    </script>
```

To access this `document.getElementById('myform').submit()`, you should change `<INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` to `<INPUT type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit">`. Don't use other element with name of `submit` or id.

And also the better one is,

```
   <script>
    window.ready = function(){
      document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').trigger('submit'); });
```

Still I don't get what is the point of submitting the form after page loads.

Comment: I automated the system, when I call a program, it automatically generates 10 numbers and opens 10 tabs filling each one in the textbox and submitting it!! just to reduce my work :)

Comment: I think he wants kind of redirect with post data.

Comment: yea yea @imsiso, please tell me how to do it

Comment: check my answer and also others all of them gives you different solutions.

Comment: @user2644795 - check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script>
function submitme()
{

    document.forms["performance"].submit();
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
function submitme()
{

    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```